# Revisiting index page after login

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new so please be willing to lend me a hand.
I am into a web application that a user needs to enter his credentials in a form set for the login page (**index.aspx**).
After he signs on, he'll be redirected to a content page (**content-page-for-user-x.aspx**).

He does open many more subpages and finally enters "index.aspx" in the browser to get back the index page.
What should I do to prevent the **index.aspx** (login form page) from showing up again? Because he is already in, not new at all. The index page now should be ***content-page-for-user-x.aspx***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In backend logic of  login page `index.aspx`, you could check if user has already logged in.

If user has already logged in, just redirect user to `content-page-for-user-x.aspx` should be fine. If user not logged in, display your login page (index.aspx) to prompt user to login.